# What is the number of consignments that would be packed in the initial $113$ hours?

Tags: linear-programming

> **QUESTION:** In a factory, $20$ workers start working on a project of packing consignments. They need exactly $5$ hours to pack one consignment. Every hour $4$ new workers join the existing workforce. It is mandatory to relieve a worker after $10$ hours. Then what is the number of consignments that would be packed in the initial $113$ hours?

---

**MY APPROACH:** It seems a bit complicated to me.. Firstly, every hour $4$ new workers join the workforce.. I don't know how to handle that.. and above that I have to subtract workers who have worked for $10$ hours.. I am sorry that this time I could not provide any working as I could not do anything as such.. I hoped to learn this here but noone has asked it before.. so I am forced to ask it.. one more thing, I do not know which tag is appropriate for this type of problem, so suggestions on that too are welcome..

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: "They need exactly 5 hours": Each worker needs 5 hours per consignment? Or 20 workers working together need 5 hours for one consignment?

Comment: @RobPratt $20$ workers together need $5$ hours to pack one consignment..